# SVG Calling JavaScript in Concrete 5

Tags: jquery, svg

I have an SVG image map on a site - I have the SVG inline. Now I want to add alternate content so decided to use the <object> method and have the SVG in an external file so I can put an image tag inside the <object>. The problem is that I am calling JavaScript functions from the onmouseover, onmouseout parameters of the SVG - and those JS functions use JQuery. The functions get called fine but I get $ is not defined. JQuery is being loaded...

I have a test page here:
http://www.kollegetown.com/themes/kollegetown/test.htm

If you open console you'll see the $ is not defined errors if you rollover a hot spot.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: self.jQuery works in chromium

Answer (score 0):

Of course you need to load jQuery. Add the following line to the SVG:

```
<script type="text/javascript" xlink:href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"/>
```

That should do the job.

Comment: Thanks much, but it doesn't do it. First, I get this error generated from JQuery:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of null  and then on rollover of anything I get: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'stop'

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the more elegant solution would be to use CSS3 animation instead of jQuery ([see Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/8sLpzuzM)):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="956px" height="745px" >
  <style type="text/css">
    a > image {
      opacity: 0;
      pointer-events:none;
      transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    }

    a > polygon {
      opacity:0;
    }

    a:hover > image {
      pointer-events:auto;
      display:inline;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  </style>

  <image x="0" y="0" width="956" height="745" xlink:href="http://www.kollegetown.com/themes/kollegetown/images/img1.jpg" />

  <!-- stadium/team -->
  <a xlink:href="/team" target="new">
  <image id="team" x="63" y="284" width="204" height="365" xlink:href="http://www.kollegetown.com/themes/kollegetown/images/homeRollover_team.jpg"/>
    <polygon points="189 383, 185 345, 155 316, 209 281, 211 244, 289 210, 291 241, 348 245, 397 290, 391 299, 344 276, 345 369, 365 385, 330 404, 313 438"/>                   
  </a>

  <!-- corporate -->            
  <a xlink:href="/corporate" target="new">
  <image id="corp" x="33" y="29" width="356" height="221" xlink:href="http://www.kollegetown.com/themes/kollegetown/images/homeRollover_corporate.jpg"/>
    <polygon points="18 126, 86 125, 186 180, 190 271, 99 327, 31 330, 18 321"/>                    
  </a>

  <!-- campus shops -->
  <a xlink:href="/campusbooster" target="new">
  <image id="shops" x="423" y="186" width="497" height="213" xlink:href="http://www.kollegetown.com/themes/kollegetown/images/homeRollover_shops.jpg"/>
    <polygon points="425 60, 427 209, 470 226, 469 246, 483 251, 506 235, 534 244, 595 214, 600 191, 612 188, 621 201, 633 196, 631 23, 624 17, 504 17"/>                   
  </a>

  <!-- art gallery / design -->
  <a xlink:href="/designs" target="new">
  <image id="design" x="496" y="407" width="331" height="321" xlink:href="http://www.kollegetown.com/themes/kollegetown/images/homeRollover_gallery.jpg"/>
    <polygon points="503 509, 438 547, 440 691, 481 710, 482 729, 647 729, 647 582"/>
  </a>

</svg>
```

There is a glitch with Opera, it does not make the overly images sensitive for mouse events on hover. But the user can still click on the building to follow the link. Couldn't test IE9 (problems with my Win7 Notebook).